# Android: ConstraintLayout has different behavior on SDK 4.1.x

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have this simple layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_1">

            <com.xxx.ui.widget.CustomTextViewFont
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="@style/FlatCardTitle"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_1"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/actions_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:customFont="OpenSans-CondBold.ttf" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/actions_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:visibility="gone">

                .....
            </FrameLayout>

       .....
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

On Android 5.x, the **actions_layout** is correctly on the right of the view. BUT in 4.1.x the **actions_layout** stills in left.

Thanks for you support guys!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Specifying top and bottom constraints helped me.
Try this way.

```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
```